# adb: command not found- Window 10 shell

Tags: shell, adb

I am trying to run the adb command using adb shell. Running well on mac but not in the window.

[image]

Comment: "How do I make software available in my PATH" isn't a software development question, and its answers are identical between programming tools and any other program. It's thus a better fit for somewhere -- like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), but unlike Stack Overflow -- where non-development-specific questions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to the folder containing `adb.exe` to the `PATH` environment variable. If you don't have `adb.exe` in your computer, download one.

(Off topic) Besides, you seems trying to run a Linux shell script on Windows, please use some software like Cygwin or MSYS2.